# solidity and react and calling a solidity function many times

Tags: solidity, react

I was looking at where i needed to go in my coding, and see i need a pattern to handle the 'many' calls.  for example a call only returns 1 set of data, when i need perhaps records 1-70.

Is the following snippet a 'good'/'bad'/'ugly' way of handling this, and if not 'good' what is a better way?

```
return countvariablecall()
.then((results) => {
    for(let i=0; i< results.c[0]; i++){
        return manyTimesCalledFunction(i).
        then ((result) => {
            do something with the result.
        )}
    }
})
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with that but just make sure you use like a redux store and pagination when you can. You might want to look into https://thegraph.com/ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do here is resolve a bunch of promises, in which case, [I would normally create an array of promises](https://shawntabrizi.com/code/programmatically-fetch-multiple-apis-parallel-using-async-await-javascript/), and resolve them all with `Promise.all()`.

Something like this:

```
// This is just an example of a function that returns a promise
function delayedNum (num) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(num);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function main() {
    // create an array for your promises
    promises = []

    // queue and push your promises to the array
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    // Note you can queue .then() statements too
        promises.push(delayedNum(i)
        .then(function(result) {
            return result * 2;
        }));
   }

  // resolve all promises and play with the results
  Promise.all(promises).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result)
  });
}
```

`console.log(result)` will be an array of the numbers 0-38, counting by 2's, in order, which you can manipulate easily.

Comment: THIS i like!  thank you.  while i expected the other way to 'work', it felt a little 'shod' together.

Comment: No prob. If it helps, you can also check out where I actually used this pattern to show UX based on a solidity view function [here](https://github.com/shawntabrizi/Ethereum-Twitter-Bounty/blob/master/twitter-bounty/src/js/app.js#L253).

Comment: actually it's very much like my migration file with the promises.all.  Thank you for pointing it out so i 'got it'.  As soon as i saw what you wrote, it was exactly what i was looking for, appreciate.